# Succinctly matching several Options at the same time

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

When you have an `Option` `aOpt` and you're only interested in doing something if it actually contains something, you can do the following:

```
aOpt match {
   case Some(a) => foo(a)  // do something
   case None => // do nothing
}
```

Which of course should be shortened to:

```
aOpt.foreach(a => foo(a))
```

Now say I have two `Option`s `aOpt` and `bOpt`. I'm interested in doing something only if *both* of these `Option`s actually contain an object.

So I write

```
(aOpt, bOpt) match {
   case (Some(a), Some(b)) => foo(a, b) // Do something
   case _ => // Do nothing
}
```

How can I shorten this to fewer lines? Or how can I at least omit the useless `case _ =>` line without warnings?

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**for-comprehension**

```
for{
  a <- aOpt
  b <- bOpt
} foo(a, b)
```

**scalaz**

*Operator `|@|`*

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
(aOpt |@| bOpt)(foo)
```

*Method `^`*

```
^(aOpt, bOpt)(foo)
```

*Operator `tuple`*

```
val abOpt = aOpt tuple bOpt // Option[(A, B)]
abOpt.foreach( case (a, b) => foo(a, b) ) // or
abOpt.foreach( (foo _) tupled _ )
```

Comment: or the third scalaz way: ^(aOpt, bOpt)(foo)

Comment: @AlexIv, thank you. Feel free to edit my answers any time when you think it will be useful.

Comment: Thanks for that comprehensive list. The for comprehension looks like the best option to me.